# The correct way to customize HTML/CSS for different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to have a fully customizable page for different users' needs, which includes different HTML and CSS. I can think of **two approaches** for this:

1. We store the HTML and CSS files in the file structure (say in
   `app/views/custom/` and `assets/stylesheets/custom/`), and store the
   links to those files in the appropriate database record.
   **Advantages:**

   1. Files are easy to create for us as they are in our text editor as normal.
   2. Security may be better because access to the DB doesn't allow someone to change the actual code (we can make sure only those folders can be referenced so someone can't change the HTML/CSS to their own destinations).
2. We store the custom HTML and custom CSS in text fields in the DB and render them with something like `<%= raw @user.custom_html %>`.

Which of these are the better approach? Is there an even better way?

Comment: Do you really need dynamic HTML templates? You can get a real long way with well structured markup and css.  I would consider if what you need is not just having different CSS themes or using modular components which the user can rearrange - like widgets on a dashboard.

Comment: how many custom views you think you will have in total ? I was thinking if you should just partially render as per each user ...if user blah  <%= render partial: 'layouts/custome_page' %>

Comment: @max I really do need fully customizable HTML templates - these users are business clients and this particular page has to look exactly how they want it to look.

Comment: @NullSoulException I don't think we'll need many custom views (at least for now), but I do need full customizability, better than inserting partials into an existing layout.